What math is the "Vector Transform" node doing under the hood?
I found a tutorial for a parallax shader that starts with connecting the "Incoming" vector-output of a "Geometry" node to the input of a "Vector Transform" node with its options set to "Type: Vector", "Convert From: World", and "Convert To: Object". What math operations is that doing under the hood? Can I do the same thing with Vector Math nodes?

Context: I want to change the calculation of the parallax shader to use a normal map instead of the default normals of the object to which it is applied, but I can't figure out how to do that.

It's doing a "coordinate system" transform.
Multiplying the vector by a matrix that contains all the values necessary to:

Translate from world to local (vector subtraction)
Rotate from world to local (vector rotation, centered on the origin)
Scale (multiply the vector by a constant)

In shaders only, you can't do that. You would need the "location" of the origin of the object, as well as the current rotation of the object.
You could use a "driver" for getting those values, but then things start getting more complicated.

Do you know if it's possible to somehow get a normal map added to this setup instead of using the default surface normal?

@Lawton, you must take from the same image texture you used for the normal map. Since the normal map is given in the shader itself, just take it from the node that generates it.

You probably "rotate" the vector taken from the map from "Z" to the "geometry normal".
